# Connecting computer and motor driver grounds

Tags: grounding, brushless-dc-motor, can, emi-filtering, robotics

I am designing a robotic system and seem to be having a ground issue whilst working with motor drivers.

To improve system stability and for EMI concerns, I have split the power and signal using an isolated DC/DC converter to power the PC and all other electronics, and powering directly from the battery for the motors and motor drivers.
The drivers and motors are controlled by the PC via CAN bus (differential.) This has worked great so far, but after adding several more nodes, the power ground starts becoming so noisy that the CAN transceiver on the PC (that has a completely different ground) can no longer communicate with the motor driver.

If I just connect both grounds, the problem goes away, but I am afraid of back EMF and returning currents and noise affecting the electronics.

What would be the best way to connect between grounds? I was thinking of a star configuration connection, close to the power supplies/battery, but I am worried of the lack of insulation. What would be the best way to connect but at the same time safeguard and filter noise from coming into the electronics?
[image: Power Disribution]

Comment: Please post a schematic and draw a dotted line to indicate the connection that you are concerned about.

Comment: If you connect the ground at some sensible location then there's no problem. Why properly designed motor drivers etc separate signal and supply ground. If they hand you a ground hooked near the motor supply as signal ground, then it's a quack design. In general the motor driver electronics shouldn't mix its own supply with the motor supply but keep those separated.

Comment: Hi, I added a schematic as you suggested. The drivers I use have the same ground and some sort of internal isolation. Should I add some sort of filter to reduce noise that might come in through the now shared ground?